# C# code on aspx page - why isn't this assigning value to hidden field

Tags: c#, webforms

I have a question that feels a bit trivial but I can't get it working.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnJsonData" runat="server" Value="<%#GetInterviewData%>"/>
```

I want to assign some json data to hdnJsonData which I plan to use with knockout.

```
using KnockoutApp.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace KnockoutApp.Tutorials
{
    public partial class WorkingWithLists : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected string GetInterviewData
        {
            get
            {
                Product product = new Product();
                product.Name = "Apple";
                product.ExpiryDate = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
                product.Price = 3.99M;
                product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small", "Medium", "Large" };
                string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);

                Product deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(output);
                return output;
            }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The breakpoint doesn't get hit on GetInterviewData.

Can someone correct my syntax?

Also I know that I can just bind the value in page load.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a server control, and would like to fill it from server data, you should simply use the back-end to fill it using Page_Load... that is the proper way to do it... now if you absolutely want to do it in the aspx:

```
<%
  string val = GetInterviewData;
%>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnJsonData" runat="server" Value="<%=val%>"/>
```

try that and let me know if this works or not... Note that to see GetInterviewData from the aspx, you may have to spell out the namespace path...

Comment: Just had a proper read of this and realized that its quite similar to my answer - however the
    
    string val ...

is not needed, the key to it working is the change to =() rather than the binding expression #().

Answer (score 0):

As you have said you can do it in the code behind, as you have acknowledged that Ill assume thats not what you are after!

Your code is currently this:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnJsonData" runat="server" Value="<%#GetInterviewData%>">
```

The problem that I see is that hdnJsonData is a server control and cant have a value assigned to it this way.

You could try

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdnJsonData" value="<%=(GetInterviewData)%>">
```

Note the shorthand response.write =() rather than a binding expression #()

---

If you really have to have hdnJsonData as a server control you could keep your code and call Page.DataBind() in the code behind - not 100% that this will work as its not an approach I would normally use, but you may have some success with it.